# string: chars removal and divide digits into blocks

Tags: c++

The problem says that you have a string consisting of digits & special chars. All you have to do is to remove all the chars and divide the digits into blocks separated by '-'. The block holds 3 digits or 2 digits but cannot be 1 alone. For example:

input: `"aasnd1df2d3dfg4gfd56f7gaad8ew9ds2sa1"`

After the removal of the chars, it should be like `"12345678921"` and then it should be divided into blocks, so the final output would be like `"123-456-789-21"`.

I made the char removal part, but I can't make the blocks division. Any ideas?

```cpp
string removeNumbers(string str)
{
    int current = 0;
    string dig;
    int len=0;
    int ctr=0;

    for(int i = 0; i < str.length(); i++){
        if (isdigit(str[i])){
            str[current] = str[i];
            current++;
        }
    }
    dig= str.substr(0,current);

    return dig;
}
```

Comment: "*I can't make the blocks division*" - why not? What is stopping you? Be specific. Have you looked at [`string::insert()`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/basic_string/insert)?

Comment: i cant apply the rule that i cant leave any number left alone ,example: if they are 7 digits they should be a block of 3 digits and two of 2 digits "1234567" to "123-45-67"

Comment: Hello and welcome to SO  I don't want to discourage you from the get-go, however, we don't usually do the homework for you  The best way you will ever learn is by challenging yourself - even if you do "reinvent the wheel" sometimes. 

People are eager to help, but you did not provide a clear description of your problem. What is the actual block splitting rule that you are expected to implement?

PS Being able to communicate abstract and complicated matters clearly is a precious skill in high demand. Practice makes better, remember that everyone started as a novice!

Comment: Okay, now I somewhat get it, though the precise rules are still not entirely clear. Assuming that each block can be only 2 or 3 characters long and that you should get as many 3's as possible a simple greedy, iterative algorithm should work. Ask those questions: Is the number of characters odd? Is it divisible by 3 or is it even? It smells like the classical change-making problem. Please check out the Wikipedia article at https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Change-making_problem.

Comment: I've implemented a solution actually for the sheer fun of it. Will post an answer later on maybe. See this gist: https://gist.github.com/pinkeen/d608680333c0d4a5cf727a4f3cc04b6f

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You first function works. However, it is a little bit too complicated and should be refactored. Also the name is wrong. It removes the NON-digits.

I will show a similar, but easier solution to you later in the code example.

Now the tricky part. You want to distribute the digits equally in a group with a given fixed size. I will explain the general approach with arbitrary group sizes to you.

Let us assume that you want to split an array of a given size into groups of a fixed size, here the array of digits (your string) into groups of size gs, in your example 3.

Then we can calculate the number of groups by a simple integer division. So, basically the number of elements in the array (number of digits in your string) devided by the group size. Since an integer division of a number by a group size will result in 0 for the first group-size elements, we will add an offset of one and get the simple formular:

```
const size_t numberOfResultingGroups = ((numberOfDigits-1) / groupSize) + 1 ;
```

This should be understandable. And how many elements will there be in one group? We can calculate this again with an integer division. So, number of elements (digits) divided by the group size. Also very straigtforward.

```
const size_t basicGoupSize = numberOfDigits / numberOfResultingGroups;
```

Also very easy to understand. But there may be a remainder as a result of the integer division. These remaining elements need also to be distributed.

We could calculate the remainder with a modulo division, but also in a classical way:

```
int digitsToDistribute = numberOfDigits - (numberOfResultingGroups * basicGoupSize);
```

Also this is simple to understand.

And note, the remainder (the digitsToDistribute) can of course never be bigger than the number of groups.

We can then in a loop use the "basicGoupSize" and add a 1 to it, as long as there are remaining "digitsToDistribute". So, in each loop run, we will check, if there are still remaining bytes to distribute, and, in case of yes, add 1 to the "basicGoupSize" and the decrement the "digitsToDistribute".

And so all bytes will be evenly distributed.

Next is the handling of a dash. Many people think of it like print something, then dash, then something, then dash, then something, then dash aso.

But the handling of the last dash may be difficult. And so, we turn the sequence around and print a dash, followed by something, followed by a dash, followed by something aso. And we simply suppress the first dash.

Everything together will lead us to the solution (This is one of many possible solutions):

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>

// Remove all non-digits from a string
std::string removeNonDigits(const std::string &str)
{
    std::string dig;

    for (unsigned int i = 0; i < str.length(); i++) {
        if (::isdigit(str[i])) {
            dig += str[i];
        }
    }
    return dig;
}

int main() {
    // Ourtest string
    std::string test{ "aasnd1df2d3dfg4gfd56f7gaad8ew9ds2sa1sdf34sdff56sdff78sdf" };
    // Remove all non digits
    std::string digits{ removeNonDigits(test) };

    // Our group length will be 3 (can be anything else)
    constexpr size_t groupSize{ 3u };

    // How many digitsdowe haveinour test string
    const size_t numberOfDigits = digits.length();

    // Trivial case: Number of digits is smaller than the desired group size. Simply print it
    if (numberOfDigits < groupSize) {
        std::cout << digits << '\n';
    }
    else {
        // Ok, now we want to build groups and distribute remainders

        // How many goups will we have? Integer division by group size (corrected for a 1 offset)
        const size_t numberOfResultingGroups{ ((numberOfDigits-1) / groupSize) + 1 };

        // A basic group will have this size. Integer division of number Of digits by number of groups
        const size_t basicGoupSize{ numberOfDigits / numberOfResultingGroups };

        // Maybe not all digits are used up. This is the remainder. 
        // We will add 1 to the basic group size as long as there are remaining digits
        int digitsToDistribute = numberOfDigits - (numberOfResultingGroups * basicGoupSize);
 
        // Handling of dashes. We will notprint a dash in front of the FIRST group
        bool printDashInFrontOfGroup = false;

        // Start position of substring
        size_t stringStartPos{};

        // No print all groups
        for (size_t i{}; i < numberOfResultingGroups; ++i) {

            // Length of group. So base length + 1, as long as there are remaining digits to distribute
            const size_t length = basicGoupSize + (((digitsToDistribute--) > 0) ? 1 : 0);

            // Print dash and sub string
            std::cout << (std::exchange(printDashInFrontOfGroup, true)?"-":"") << digits.substr(stringStartPos, length);

            // And,next start position
            stringStartPos += length;
        }
    }
    return 0;
}
```

---

**Edit**

Some additional note:

All the above algorithm is deterministic. It will give the mathematical correct solution. Predictable. For different group sizes.

As a basic rule. Make your design, the mathematics and the algorithm before start coding. Then implement everything.

Example: Removing non digits from a string in C++ is a really very short one-liner:

```
// Remove all-non-digits
test = std::regex_replace(test, std::regex(R"([^0-9])"), "");
```

That is basically very simple and actually a no brainer. Anyway. People may do it differently, or more complicated. For whatever reason.

And as said, if you do your design **before** coding then you can come up with really compact solutions. One of many possible examples:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <regex>
#include <algorithm>
#include <vector>
#include <experimental/iterator>

auto splitToEqualParts(const std::string s, const size_t groupSize) {

    std::vector<std::string> result{};  // Here we will store all the split string parts
      
    int toDistribute = (int)s.size() - (((((int)s.size() - 1) / (int)groupSize) + 1) * (int)(s.size() / ((((int)s.size() - 1) / (int)groupSize) + 1)));

    // Add all sub-string parts to result vector
    for (size_t i{}, pos{}, length{}; i < (size_t)((((int)s.size() - 1) / (int)groupSize) + 1); ++i, pos += length) {

        length = (s.size() / ((((int)s.size() - 1) / (int)groupSize) + 1)) + (toDistribute-- > 0) * 1;
        result.push_back(s.substr(pos, length));
    }
    return result;
}

int main() {

    // Some test string
    std::string test{ "aasnd1df2d3dfg4gfd56f7gaad8ew9ds2sa1sdf34sdff56sdff78sdf" };

    // Remove all-non-digits
    test = std::regex_replace(test, std::regex(R"([^0-9])"), "");

    // Split into equal parts
    std::vector part{ splitToEqualParts(test, 3) };

    std::copy(part.begin(), part.end(), std::experimental::make_ostream_joiner(std::cout, "-"));
    return 0;
}
```

Compiled and tested with GCC and Clang. Using C++17.

Of course the common sub expressions maybe put in const variables. But basically no need. An optimizing compiler will do it for you.

The above will work for all group sizes (>0) and any number of digits in the string . . .

Comment: I did not test your code (it may be very wel working) but it seems to be taking the hard route. As I've mentioned in the comment under OP it reminded me of the change-making problem. It belongs to the same class of problems where the most naive,  greedy iterative approach is often the most optimal one. The twist is it that it requires exactly one step lookahead. Here's my impl: https://gist.github.com/pinkeen/d608680333c0d4a5cf727a4f3cc04b6f

Comment: @pinkeen: I edited the above answer. It takes the idiomatic correct approach. The problem can be solved in a deterministic way. You can calculate everything upfront. So, first design and then coding. And, because of a mathematical approach, it works for all kind of group lengths >0 and all strings, including the empty string.  Your example on github is somehow very complicated. And in my opinion does not produce the desired output. You show in most cases only groups of 2, where there should be groups of 3. But no worries. It does not matter. OP is gone since long and will not read all this

Answer (score 0):

I suggest

```
#include <string>
#include <iostream>
#include <algorithm>

using namespace std;

string remove_chars(string & s)
{
    string inter_result;
    for_each(s.begin(), s.end(), [&inter_result](char c) { if (isdigit(c)) inter_result += c; });

    size_t length = inter_result.length();
    if (length <= 3)
    {
        return inter_result;
    }

    string result;
    size_t pos = 0, step = 3;

    while (pos < length)
    {
        if (length - pos - 3 == 1) step = 2;
        if (result.length() > 0)
        {
            result += "-";
        }
        result += inter_result.substr(pos, step);
        pos += step;
    }
    return result;
}

int main()
{
    string s = "aasnd1df2d3dfg4gfd56f7gaad8ew9ds2sa1";

    cout << remove_chars(s) << endl;
    return 0;
}
```